# Monaco-editor: disable all suggestions

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using Monaco to edit plain text and I want to disable all kind of suggestions.
I disabled all suggestions options. However, when I press "CTRL + Space", monaco is still showing a popup with a message "No suggestions". See an example at https://codesandbox.io/s/monaco-suggestions-issue-hq1j9

[image: screenshot of suggestions]

Does anyone know how can I disable this tooltip?

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are describing (on Chrome, OSX). Tried CMD+Enter too.

Comment: Sorry. I typed "Ctrl + Enter" but I would like to say "CTRL + Space"... My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

add this code after assigning `this.editor` in `LanguageTextInput.componentDidMount` to override the command:

```js
this.editor.addCommand(Monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | Monaco.KeyCode.Space, function() {
    // you can add some functionality here for this key combination
});
```

Now when you press Ctrl+Space nothing happens.