# monaco-editor remove default autocompletion suggestions for custom language

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, monaco-editor

There are similar questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581570/how-to-remove-autocompletions-for-monaco-editor-using-javascript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70605597/how-to-remove-default-dom-browser-related-autocompletions-for-monaco-editor-usin), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69810342/adding-custom-limited-javascript-autocomplete-set-to-monaco-editor-with-addextra?noredirect=1&lq=1) but the answers described there work only for non-custom languages like C#, JavaScript and TypeScript.

What I want to achieve is to get rid of suggestions based on the previously typed words.
[image]

And I also want to keep my custom suggestions added with `registerCompletionItemProvider`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monaco-editor by default provide suggestions based on the previously typed words on the editor. In order to get only the custom added suggestions, you can provide the suggestions through **registerCompletionItemProvider** and it will override any default suggestions provided by moncao-editor.

Example:

```js
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('myCustomLanguage', {
  provideCompletionItems: function(model, position) {
    const suggestions = [
      {
        label: 'console',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
        documentation: 'Logs a message to the console.',
        insertText: 'console.log()',
      },
      {
        label: 'setTimeout',
        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
        documentation: 'Executes a function after a specified time interval.',
        insertText: 'setTimeout(() => {\n\n}, 1000)',
      }
    ];

    return { suggestions: suggestions };
  }
});
```

If you type something now, it will not suggest anything that was earlier typed. On pressing  *Ctrl+Space*, you would see only the above two suggestions("console" & "setTimeOut") on the editor.

Comment: Thank you! I got custom logic in `registerCompletionItemProvider`. And there is a case when I return empty array in suggestions. In this case it suggests words that I typed earlier. How to deal with that?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't get any default suggestion even if you are returning suggestions as empty. You may try setting 'quickSuggestions' property in monaco-editor as false.
Just add quickSuggestions: false when creating the editor using monaco.editor.create

Comment: Well, it removes all of the suggestions

Comment: Not sure why you are getting so. For me without setting 'quickSuggestions: false', I get 'no suggestions' like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59839148/monaco-editor-disable-all-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after some searching and (try and fail) I finally get it.

Just set 'showWords: false' in the 'suggest' configuration, inside the editor creation function:

```js
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("editorContainer"), {
  value: jsCode,
  language: "typescript", //can use your custom language here
  suggest: {
    showWords: false
  }
});
```